# Multi-complex arithmetic in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How can I go about performing [multi-complex arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicomplex_number) in MATLAB?

Comment: I don't know about any built-in commands, but, I could derive a matrix representation that you could build in matlab if interested.

Comment: Are multicomplex number at all related to [hypercomplex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number)?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: I actually just found one myself (see answer below), thanks though!

Comment: @horchler: They are a different generalization of complex numbers, so I imagine implementing multicomplex numbers and hypercomplex numbers in MATLAB will be very similar but obviously not the same.

Comment: I should talk to you more about what you are doing... let me digest that paper a bit.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: Sure. It's a method for numerically stable differentiation; it just says that $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \Im{f(x + ih)} / h$ for analytic $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and it generalizes that to higher-order derivatives.

Comment: Sounds like [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/) for the basic case. [Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20614488/2278029).

Comment: @horchler: Yeah, that's where I became familiar with it.

Comment: @horchler It is not clear how to work with multicomplex numbers. How to extract imaginary parts from them. This works a little differently than just $imag()$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found an implementation in this paper:
[Computation of higher-order derivatives using the multi-complex
step method](http://folk.ntnu.no/preisig/HAP_Specials/AdvancedSimulation_files/2014/AdvSim-2014__Verheule_Adrian_Complex_differenetiation.pdf)

The paper describes everything in detail, but the overall idea is to make a `classdef`.